# Retaining n number of categories in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame and would like to only retain n number of categories in selected columns. For example, in column `Cat_1` I would like to only retain the top 3 most populous categories while in `Cat_2` I would like to retain only the top two categories (with the other categories given an `NA` value). Below is an example data frame.

```
test_df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                      Cat_1 =c("test1","test1","test2","test2","test3","test3","test4","test5","test6","test7"),
                      Cat_2 = c("no1","no2","no3","no4","no5","no5","no6","no6","no7","no8"))

ID Cat_1 Cat_2
 1 test1   no1
 2 test1   no2
 3 test2   no3
 4 test2   no4
 5 test3   no5
 6 test3   no5
 7 test4   no6
 8 test5   no6
 9 test6   no7
10 test7   no8
```

Below is the desired outcome.

```
outcome_df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
           Cat_1 = c("test1","test1","test2","test2","test3","test3",NA_real_,NA_real_,NA_real_,NA_real_),
           Cat_2 = c(NA_real_,NA_real_,NA_real_,NA_real_,"no5","no5","no6","no6",NA_real_,NA_real_))

ID Cat_1 Cat_2
 1 test1  <NA>
 2 test1  <NA>
 3 test2  <NA>
 4 test2  <NA>
 5 test3   no5
 6 test3   no5
 7  <NA>   no6
 8  <NA>   no6
 9  <NA>  <NA>
10  <NA>  <NA>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fct_lump_n` from `forcats` to keep top `n` levels.

```
library(purrr)
library(forcats)

n <- c(3, 2)
test_df[-1] <- map2(test_df[-1], n, fct_lump_n, other_level = NA)
test_df

#   ID Cat_1 Cat_2
#1   1 test1  <NA>
#2   2 test1  <NA>
#3   3 test2  <NA>
#4   4 test2  <NA>
#5   5 test3   no5
#6   6 test3   no5
#7   7  <NA>   no6
#8   8  <NA>   no6
#9   9  <NA>  <NA>
#10 10  <NA>  <NA>
```

We can also do this using `Map`:

```
test_df[-1] <- Map(function(x, y) fct_lump_n(x, y, other_level = NA), test_df[-1], n)
```